# How to solve this for any constant k?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have to solve this:
$$r’(t)=\frac{-3}{\lambda}(r(t))^2+ k$$ 
Where k is a constant
I was able to solve it when k is 0 but I’m not able to solve it for any k.

Comment: This is separable $$\int \frac{dr}{k - 3 r^{2}/ \lambda} = \int dt$$ then use a trig substitution.

Answer (score 0):

*One possible trick since the equation is separable.*

Write $$-\frac 3\lambda r^2+k=-\frac 3\lambda \left(r-\frac{\sqrt{k} \sqrt{\lambda }}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(r+\frac{\sqrt{k} \sqrt{\lambda }}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$ making, after partial fraction decomposition $$\frac {dr}{-\frac 3\lambda r^2+k}=\frac{ \sqrt{3\lambda }}{2 \sqrt{k}}\left(\frac{1}{3r+ \sqrt{k} \sqrt{3\lambda }}-\frac{1}{3 r- \sqrt{k}
   \sqrt{3\lambda }} \right)\,dr=dt$$ You will get two logarithms and back to $r(t)$, "probably" a $\tanh(.)$ function (as Mattos suggested).

Comment: The problem is with the minus, to get a tanh(.) we should have    $$\frac{3}{\lambda}r^2$$ without the negative sign in the beginning

Comment: @LamarA.Chidiac Don't confuse $\tanh$ with $\tan$. A $+r^2$ would give a $\tan$ solution. But $\tanh$ is the hyperbolic tangent

Comment: Oh okay sorry. Thank you:)